# Anti-theft axle nut covers?

Tags: axle, theft

Been looking high and low for a 15mm diameter axle nut cover. Like a rounded-out protective cover that uses hex or torx keys to remove in order to discourage wheel theft. I'm finding plenty of options for motorcycles but I'm going, ahem, NUTS, trying to find something that would work for bicycles!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  This seems very close to a shopping question; we may have to see how the community feels about it

Comment: That might indeed be a shopping question. But there are resources online (for example this article from 2016, but that seem to remain valid for the most part): https://www.cyclingabout.com/list-ways-theft-proof-wheels-secure-components-locking-security-skewers-seatpost-locks/ Is it the kind of products you are looking for, and if not, can you be more accurate?

Comment: why do you need a cover that uses a hex to remove, in order to cover an axle nut that, presumably, also uses a hex to remove?

Comment: Can you store your bicycle more-securely? Take it inside helps enormously.

Comment: Yeah, these are all great suggestions of course. At the shop I work at we have people come in every week with wheels stolen. Even in broad daylight outside of where they work, so sometimes they just can't bring them inside. The skewers you can put through a hollow-core axle are great. But I'm talking about something to replace or cover the 15mm nuts that you use on a wheel with a solid core axle when mounting it in the dropouts.

Answer (score 3):

To try and answer in a way that's not just a product recommendation: It's hard to imagine a better design in this category than the Pitlocks for solid axles. You don't want something that it's even possible for a tool to grab on to, you want a rotating sleeve of ultra-hard material.

Comment: Oh great! Yes, that is a great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Could you offer up a picture of what "Pitlocks for solid axles" looks like? That is a foreign term to me.

Comment: Is it ok for me to post a link? I'm new to StackExchange and still looking through to make sure I wouldn't be called out for soliciting or anything. But basically, the Pitlock axle nut set replaces the nuts on a solid axle (not a skewer) and requires a special, proprietary tool to remove.